# searching multiple strings in multiple files inside a directory and printing the string and corresponding file name where it was found

Tags: grep, search

I have around 500 strings and I want to search for the files which contain them inside a directory and get the file names which contain the strings. So far I've been using:

```
find -name 'LYFNRE.*' -exec grep -f file1.txt {} \; -print
```

but the problem is a string can be found in many files so it is difficult to find which strings are present and which are missing due to the huge output. Can you help me in printing the strings with their corresponding file names where they were found.

Answer (score 2):

You should just let `grep` give you the filenames. GNU `grep` can do this:

```
grep -HFf ../strings.txt *
```

That will present you with output that looks like:

```
[filename]:[matched_line]
```

...for every match on every file in the directory. You can get line numbers as well:

```
grep -HnFf ../strings.txt *
```

...which provides...

```
[filename]:[line_number]:[matched_line]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're passing one file at a time to `grep`. When `grep` sees a single file on its command line, it assumes that you know exactly where you'r searching, so it doesn't display the file name in front of matches.

A trick to force `grep` to always output a file name is to also pass `/dev/null` (where there won't be any match ever). Some grep implementations have an option for that: `-H`.

Additionally, you can use `-exec … {} +` instead of `-exec … {} \;` to execute the program for many files in one go. This is faster. You should still pass `/dev/null` or `-H`, because it could happen that the command is invoked on exactly one file, either because there is a single matching file or because there are many matches requiring that `grep` is invoked several times and one time happens to concern a single file.

```
find -name 'LYFNRE.*' -exec grep -f file1.txt /dev/null {} +
```

GNU grep and recent BSD implementations (including OSX) support options to call `grep` recursively without requiring `find`.

```
grep -R --include='LYFNRE.*' -f file1.txt -H .
```

Alternatively, you can do recursive globbing in your shell. In zsh, this works out of the box. In bash, you need to run `shopt -s globstar` first, and beware that bash recurses through symbolic links to directories (unlike `find` or zsh).

```
grep -f file1.txt /dev/null **/LYFNRE.*
```

Answer (score 0):

use egrep:

```
egrep -n "str1|str2|str3" file_names
```

-n will print line number in the specific file the string was found

Comment: It's not using `egrep` that makes a difference, it's passing the whole list of file names on the command line (and you don't explain how to do that).

Comment: well that depends on the where the files are located. If there is a constant list of files, you can use:

    "for f in ${file_list[@]} ; do echo $f ; egrep -n str1|str2|str3 $f ; done" .

if all files are in same directory:

   "egrep -rn "str1|str2" dir_name" .

if there is a constant list of directories that include all the files, use:

   "for dir in ${dir_list[@]} ; do egrep -rn "str1|str2" dir_name ; done" .

read man egrep for input/out specifications, but it is pretty similar to grep