# Determine whether strings in file exist or not in file hierarchy

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a list of 500 strings.  I want to know if they either do or do not exist within 18566 files in 1770 folders.  I need to store the resulting output.  How do I do that?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137735/searching-multiple-strings-in-multiple-files-inside-a-directory-and-printing-the

Comment: The original question made a point of saying they were using Windows, but at the same time mentioned the Unix tool `grep` in the tags. Since this is a Unix-specific site, I have removed the references to Windows from the question. If the original user can't use the answers given here due to their non-Unix system, then they will need to ask the question again on a site such as [SuperUser](https://superuser.com), which allows questions on a broader range of operating systems.

Comment: do you mean that for each string, you want to find if that string appears in some file; or that for each _file_, you want to find if that file contains any of those strings? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The `-l` option will generally print the files' names matching the search term(s). The `-r` option will allow grep to also go inside each directory found. An option of `-f` will tell grep that what is given as patterns is a file and the `-F` option will tell grep to search for exact matches, not regexes.

Assuming that the list of strings is inside a file called `list`, each word to match is in its line, and that there is some pattern to match all folders to examine. We can do this:

```
grep -Ff 'list' -rl folders*
```

I do not know how a carriage return at the end of each line will affect grep's ability to match lines, or correctly process the values in `list`. You should try with a small list in a folder with a few files.